# Should a PUT request be compatible with a GET response from the same resource

Tags: rest

I'm reviewing a number of endpoints that have been developed against the beginnings of what will be a complex API.

Are there any industry recommended best practises that say that you should ensure that a response of a GET request can be used as the payload for a PUT request against the same resource.

Additionally, I would appreciate feedback of potential pitfalls people have had taking this approach.

Comment: [*"...the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server"*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), which is what a subsequent GET would return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 'it helps', but it's not strictly necessary. Because content-negotiation and multiple representations are a thing, you could use a different media type for 'changing' vs 'retrieving' the state of a resource.

If the representation of your request is a simple subset, maybe `PATCH` is what you're looking for.

If the response of a `PUT` request contains an `ETag` it is expected that the request body of the `PUT` perfectly matches byte-for-byte the current state. In reality this is rarely the case though, because API's tend to re-serialize their model and will often have subtle differences.

Having that ETag there is helpful though, because a smarter client can read that ETag and use that to warm their current cached state of the resource, and also avoids a race condition if more `PUT`'s are needed in the future and the client wants to use ETags to avoid the lost update problem.

For me personally, I like the ability to `GET` a resource, change a single property `PUT` the complete resource again.